# Jquery get last table td after dynamically appending

Tags: jquery

In the last for loop I am trying to grow the number in the last td by the growth rate(gr) and add it to the next td, then use that to calculate the next and so on. but the for loop always gets the first td value and it never updates to the recently appended td

```
var n = 10,
fcf = 1,
gr = 10;

for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
 $('table tbody tr:first').append('<td>'+i+'</td>');
}

$('table tbody').append('<tr><td>'+fcf+'</td></tr>');

for(a = 0; a <= n; a++){

var current = $('table tbody tr:last td:last-child').text();
var toint = parseInt(current, 4);
var newint = toint * (gr / 100) + toint;
$('table tbody tr:last').append('<td>'+newint+'</td>');
}
```

Comment: Also tried it with an array instead of table and it does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this you should use this:

```
$('tbody tbody tr:last').append('<td>'+newint+'</td>');
```

You should use this:

```
$('table tbody tr:last').append('<td>'+newint+'</td>');
```

It works for me.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo, the latter is what I have in my code. Not sure why it never gets the newly appended td to calulate the newint from though, it just populates the rest of the tds with 1.1 :-(

Comment: It works fine with your solution but you have to use 
`Number(current);`
instead of 
`parseInt(current, 4);`

Comment: use the toPrecision() function if you want to get a numbers like: `1 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.8 2.0 2.2 2.4 2.6`
`$('table tbody tr:last').append('<td>'+newint.toPrecision(2)+'</td>');`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `parseInt(current, 4);` which parses to integer but with radix `4`. I think you want to use base of `10` ;)

Please amend your code to `parseInt(current, 10);` it will give you an integer with a base of 10.

Here is more on it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/parseInt

Comment: Thanks for that, but do you have any solution for the problem at hand?

Comment: @1000iq you have to change the second argument to 10 or just remove it, it's default value is 10 :)